# Form.SetDesktopLocation randomly fails, getting then the form back to its original position

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working in Winforms C#.
After getting the previous location of the form from database i need to display it at the same place, so i use the SetDesktopLocation on it in the shown event. But sometime randomly, the form pops up on the wanted location and directly gets back to the location it firstly appears with the show method.
If i recursively call the shown event when the location is incorrect, it then set it correctly.

```
    private void Form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetDesktopLocation(location_x, location_y);
        if(this.Location.X != location_x)
        {
            _log.Debug($"How can that be !??! location_x = {location_x} and form location x = {this.Location.X}");
            _log.Debug($"Let's try that correct that");
            Form_Shown(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

I cannot understand the root cause of this weird behavior. Does someone met this problem already ?

Many thanks for your time and for sharing your science with me.

Comment: Set the Form's `StartPosition` to `Manual`, comment out all the `if` block, put a BreakPoint in `SetDesktopLocation(location_x, location_y);` and verify the values retuned by those fields(?)/properties(?).

Comment: Also keep in mind, SetDesktopLocation is using Desktop coordinates and this.Location is in Screen coordinates. Maybe these are the same but maybe not.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers, unfortunately setting the StartPosition property to manual does not change anything. The location_x and location_y contains correct int values. And when i recursively recall the event and thus the SetDesktopLocation with the same values, it is repainted on the right place. Of course this is only a workaround and not a solution.

Comment: This is not supposed to go wrong, but certainly can go wrong.  There is also a UI Automation event for this that any program on your machine can hook into.  Something obnoxious that insists you shouldn't overlap its window for example, but anything is possible.  Don't keep this code, it is far too dangerous.

Comment: Indeed it is dangerous and i don't like it at all. The infinite loop is at my door with it. Do you have any idea how to avoid this behavior ?

Comment: I did change my code to only recall SetDesktopLocation method once if needed, and not recursively calling the shown event. This way i will avoid the infinite loop risk. Until now it seems ok. But the problem appears only once in a while so... We'll see. Many thanks to all of you for your help.